# Last character/line not recognized using tesseract

Tags: tesseract, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I was working on a project that would use Tesseracts to recognize C code from image with some fault, and than enhance it by keyword lexicon and syntax rules. Working on it in python using pytesseract library, and every time I use it it doesn't recognize last character that is closed curly bracket. I thought that it was something I did in code that removed it so I ran it in console with that same image. and got the same result
[image: The image I was using]

from this image i got everything right except for last closed curly bracket. I also tried adding something after that last bracket but it didn't recognize that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default page segmentation mode is 3 and all I needed to do was change it to 6.
I thought 6 is a default.